# How to change the input variant of mbrn/material-table while inline edit mode?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In MUIv5 the default variant of textfield seems to have changed, so the new variant is breaking styling around in the input field while in edit mode & have a padding & marging around it which is taking too much space.

Tried overriding css, but it was not what i want. I want to override the variant of those input fields.

Answer (score 0):

We can override default props for any MUI component with the theme file like the following-

```
const defaultTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        variant: 'standard'
      }
    }
  }
});
```